# display gridview on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

First i try to displaly gridview on pageload so girdveiw succesffully displayed now i try to display when click on button i try below code but grid not visible

Code

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public DataTable info(string id)
      try
        {
            Entities2 wr = new Entities2();
            List<spv_Result> sv = wr.spvec(id).ToList();
            dt.Columns.Add("RowNumber", typeof(int));
            foreach (var c in sv)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(c.RowNumber);
            }     
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

    }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        info(id);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

there is data in dt but gridview not display

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="display nowrap"
    Width="100%" CellPadding="0"
    Font-Names="Verdana" BackColor ="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderWidth="1px" Font-Size="9pt">
<FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
```

any solution?

Comment: place try catch block in button click and check if exception coming at breakpoint

Comment: i done with try catch but there is no exception occur @mudassirhasan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "dt" has no value in below line for button click event.

```
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Try this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = info(id);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

or 

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = info(id);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Here, "info" method directly returns datatable, then values are assigned to Gridview.

Comment: i try your code but not works and grid is not display

Comment: what are you getting in Datatable dt. kindly use break point and check.

Comment: grid is inside these tags..  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

Comment: where did you place your button inside the UpdatePanel or OutSide? If Outside then add trigger if not then place it Outside

Comment: I tried with breakpoint, its working.... please make sure that your "dt" will return any value while debugging from "info" method. Also make sure that Gridview having Closing tag...

Comment: Gridview inside these tag                                                             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnl" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>